# Jersey Startup Issue : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newIdentityHashSet()

Tags: java, rest, jersey, guava, weblogic12c

I am using Jersey 2.5.1. I have my .war file packaged inside my .ear file. In the WEB-INF\lib folder of the .war module I have guava-14.0.1.jar. jersey-common-2.5.1.jar has dependency on guava.

Outside, in the ear/lib folder I have another guava jar --> guava-17.0 which is required by my project.

Both the jars have the method newIdentityHashSet(), but still I face the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newIdentityHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.(CommonConfig.java:220)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$State.(ResourceConfig.java:110)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.(ResourceConfig.java:351)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:444)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:302)
>           Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

I have tried removing one of the guava jars, but the error is same. I have tried keeping same version in both the places. But didn't work.

I am deploying in Weblogic 12C.

Any help on this will be great.

Comment: Well, the method seems to exist. Have you tried to get the source code of guava and include it in your sources folder, then built it along with the rest of the project?

Comment: No.Didn't try that. I'll try it out

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea. You should not be building Guava, but linking to it

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to have duplicated jar files into the same ear/war file. Because errors of this type will appear. The best practice is to have only one version by library.

With that being said, you can check where is trying to load the class that don't have that method:

One way to check from which jar file are loaded specific classes, is setting the parameter: **-verbose:class**  to the JRE.

This will give you a hint on this classloading issue.

Also WLS has bundled Classloader Analysis Tool (CAT) that helps you to identify duplicated jar files (conflicts, etc.)